# How to save and retrieve text which is in UITextView using plist

Tags: iphone

Hi How to save and retrieve text which is in UITextView? If anybody knows please help me. Give me some sample code using plist.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJIAAFJ) and [`writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJDIDCE)

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.plist"];
NSError *error = nil;

// read from plist:
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (!text) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading - %@", error);
}
textView.text = text;

// save to plist:
NSString *text = textView.text
if (![text writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error saving - %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It saves in plist but how to retrive it? Please help me